# Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module '

Tags: cucumber, cypress

When I try to run cypress using Cucumber, I got

[image]

This is the structure of the folders

[image]

The file I am trying to run is purchaseOrderCheckScreen.feature

Cypress package version: 9.7.0
Cypress binary version: 9.7.0
Electron version: 18.0.4
Bundled Node version:
16.13.2